# Summing the values in database

Tags: python, list, dictionary, sum

I've got simple database, the entries are made by this code:

```
base += [{
            'name': name, 
            'quantity': int(quantity),
            'price': float(price)
        }]
        magazine_base['base'] = base
        magazine_base.close()
```

I print it using:

```
print "|%16s |" % entry['name'],'%14s' % entry['quantity'],'|' '%15s' % entry['price'],'|''%15s' % float(float(entry['price'])*float(entry['quantity'])),'|'
```

And I want to sum the last column of this (quantity*price)

I was trying something with sum (base.itervalues()) but no succed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`base` is a list of dictionaries. You want the `price` key times the `quantity` key from each dictionary. `itervalues` is a method on `dict` objects to give you all the values, but you're calling it on the list `base`!

What you want instead is to sum the list comp (or genexp, either way)

```
total = sum([d['quantity'] * d['price'] for d in base])
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm just starting with python.
I've got another problem, with same base.
I'm working on I think a little bit overcomplicated database
It structure is following:
<code>def load_data():
    global base
    global magazine_base
    magazine_base = shelve.open('magazine_base')
    if magazine_base.has_key('base'):
        base = magazine_base['base']
        if not base:
            base = []
    else:
        base = []
        magazine_base['base'] = base</code>

Comment: and i've got function to clear it but it not always working properly, what's the reason? 
<code>
def removeall():
    global magazine_base
    global base
    magazine_base.clear()
    magazine_base.items() </code>

Comment: Sounds like you need to ask a new question